# Migration issue from vs2008 to vs2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I have Solution in vs2008 with framework 2.0. Now I migrated solution to vs2010 .net framework 2, and it works.

Here problem occur when I changed framework from 2.0 to 4.0, after that when I run application(win-form) it throws error on resource file saying

> "System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly
>   'SpServer.resources, Version=1.0.0.2, Culture=en-US,
>   PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot
>   find the file specified. File name: 'SpServer.resources,
>   Version=1.0.0.2, Culture=en-US, PublicKeyToken=null' --->
>   System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly
>   '...SpServer.resources.dll' or one of its dependencies. The system
>   cannot find the file specified.

I have not made any extra resource file, and assembly was not satellite assembly too before if there is error. Please let me know how to sort out this issue.

Answer (score 1):

From MSDN:

> Beginning with the .NET Framework 4, the AssemblyResolve event is raised for satellite assemblies. This change affects an event handler that was written for an earlier version of the .NET Framework, if the handler tries to resolve all assembly load requests. Event handlers that ignore assemblies they do not recognize are not affected by this change: They return null, and normal fallback mechanisms are followed.

Please also see my answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8482799/166286).