# Cosmos DB .NET SDK: could not find 'resources.dll' that never existed

Tags: c#, .net, dll, azure-cosmosdb, cultureinfo

Yes, I know this question looks similar to [C# - 'Resources' DLL failing to be loaded as it doesn't exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5755852/c-sharp-resources-dll-failing-to-be-loaded-as-it-doesnt-exist-how-might-i), but my question is about a DLL that **I do not own.** That other question involves the author's own DLL that they wrote.

**EDIT:** after solving the problem, it turns out to have been the exact same scenario. I have self-flagged my own question as a duplicate.

### Background

I am writing a C# library that uses the Cosmos DB .NET SDK 3.32.2. Sometimes, this library throws an exception because it could not find `Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Direct.resources.dll`. This file **never existed** in the first place; the `Cosmos.Direct` DLL ships with `en-US` invariant culture resources **embedded inside the DLL**. Yes, I decompiled it to check - `Cosmos.Direct` seems to be part of the SDK that the Cosmos team didn't release as open-source.

To be clear, **I do not control** `Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Direct.dll`. That is my dependency. FYI, the NuGet package for `Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos` ships with four DLLs, one of them being `Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Direct.dll`.

```
FooBar.OurCustomExceptionType: One or more errors occurred. ---> System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. ---> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'file:///C:\Foo\Bar\Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Direct.resources.dll' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

   at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly._nLoad(AssemblyName fileName, String codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly locationHint, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalGetSatelliteAssembly(String name, CultureInfo culture, Version version, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
   at System.Resources.ManifestBasedResourceGroveler.GetSatelliteAssembly(CultureInfo lookForCulture, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
   at System.Resources.ManifestBasedResourceGroveler.GrovelForResourceSet(CultureInfo culture, Dictionary`2 localResourceSets, Boolean tryParents, Boolean createIfNotExists, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
   at System.Resources.ResourceManager.InternalGetResourceSet(CultureInfo requestedCulture, Boolean createIfNotExists, Boolean tryParents, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
   at System.Resources.ResourceManager.InternalGetResourceSet(CultureInfo culture, Boolean createIfNotExists, Boolean tryParents)
   at System.Resources.ResourceManager.GetString(String name, CultureInfo culture)
   at Microsoft.Azure.Documents.StoreResult.CreateStoreResult(StoreResponse storeResponse, Exception responseException, Boolean requiresValidLsn, Boolean useLocalLSNBasedHeaders, Uri storePhysicalAddress)
   at Microsoft.Azure.Documents.StoreReader.<ReadMultipleReplicasInternalAsync>d__14.MoveNext()
   
   ... long stack trace ...

   at FooBar.OurCustomCosmosWrapper`1.<GetItemAsync>d__4.MoveNext()
```

Looking at the stack trace, the library is searching for a "satellite assembly" of resources that never existed, even though the resources are embedded in the DLL.

I have set my own app to use `[assembly: NeutralResourcesLanguage("en-US", UltimateResourceFallbackLocation.MainAssembly)]` in AssemblyInfo.cs, but clearly that is not affecting this Cosmos dependency library. It only affects my own FooBar assembly that takes a dependency on the Cosmos SDK.

### My question

How do I force my one of my dependency DLLs (in this case, Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Direct.dll) to use its own embedded resources instead of trying to find a separate `resources.dll` file that doesn't exist?

I bet this could be one of a few problems:

- There is some way to set dependency assembly resource loading in App.config or some other project config file that I don't know about. Remember: I don't need to set this for my own library; I need to set this for one of my dependencies.
- This is a bug in the Cosmos SDK.
- I missed a culture-related setting somewhere when importing the Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos package.

Comment: Can you describe how you are deploying your application? Are you relying on Nuget to resolve dependencies or do you have a custom system that copies/loads DLLs? Can you provide a repro? How does your CSPROJ look like? Are you depending on another project that also has an SDK dependency? How is dependency conflict resolved if any?

This is not a common error or something that has been reported on https://github.com/Azure/azure-cosmos-dotnet-v3/issues?q=is%3Aissue+is%3Aopen+%22resources.dll%22

Comment: We are resolving this internally then I'll post an update that is safe and makes sense to the public SO community. I posted this hoping I made an obvious C# mistake, maybe not even specific to Cosmos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was not Cosmos's fault; we actually had an [AppDomain.AssemblyResolve](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.appdomain.assemblyresolve) handler registered somewhere else that was intercepting assembly loads, even if they were embedded assemblies, and was attempting to load them from a specific location as a .dll file. This file never existed, so it would fail.

That SO post I originally mentioned in my question? [C# - 'Resources' DLL failing to be loaded as it doesn't exist](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8482799/9655768)

It did in fact solve the problem. Just search your repo for `AssemblyResolve`, check to see if a handler function was registered for it, then makes sure that handler returns `null` (or `nullptr` if in C++) when it encounters one of your embedded resource assemblies.